# Anonymous mmap zero-filled?

Tags: memory, freebsd, mmap

[In Linux, the mmap(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) explains that an anonymous mapping

> . . . is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.

[The FreeBSD mmap(2) man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mmap&sektion=2) does not make a similar guarantee about zero-filling, though it does promise that bytes after the end of a file in a non-anonymous mapping are zero-filled.

**Which flavors of Unix promise to return zero-initialized memory from anonymous mmaps? Which ones return zero-initialized memory in practice, but make no such promise on their man pages?**

It is my impression that zero-filling is partially for security reasons. I wonder if any mmap implementations skip the zero-filling for a page that was mmapped, munmapped, then mmapped again by a single process, or if any implementations fill a newly mapped page with pseudorandom bits, or some non-zero constant.

P.S. [Apparently, even brk and sbrk used to guarantee zero-filled pages.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/net.unix-wizards/Ls9_9KAQ6d4) My experiments on Linux seem to indicate that, even if full pages are zero-filled upon page fault after a sbrk call allocates them, partial pages are not:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const intptr_t many = 100;
  char * start = sbrk(0);
  sbrk(many);
  for (intptr_t i = 0; i < many; ++i) {
    start[i] = 0xff;
  }
  printf("%d\n",(int)start[many/2]);
  sbrk(many/-2);
  sbrk(many/2);
  printf("%d\n",(int)start[many/2]);
  sbrk(-1 * many);
  sbrk(many/2);
  printf("%d\n",(int)start[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Which flavors of Unix promise to return zero-initialized memory from anonymous mmaps?*

### GNU/Linux

As you said in your question, the [Linux version of mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) promises to zero-fill anonymous mappings:

> `MAP_ANONYMOUS`
>
> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.

### NetBSD

The [NetBSD version of mmap](https://man.netbsd.org/mmap.2) promises to zero-fill anonymous mappings:

> `MAP_ANON`
>
> Map anonymous memory not associated with any specific file.  The file descriptor is not used for creating `MAP_ANON` regions, and must be specified as `-1`.  The mapped memory will be zero filled.

### OpenBSD

The [OpenBSD manpage of mmap](https://man.openbsd.org/mmap.2) does not promise to zero-fill anonymous mappings. However, Theo de Raadt (prominent OpenBSD developer), declared in [November 2019 on the OpenBSD mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-bugs&m=157403903112173):

> Of course it is zero filled.  What else would it be?  There are no plausible alternatives.
>
> I think it detracts from the rest of the message to say something so obvious.

And the other OpenBSD developers did not contradict him.

### IBM AIX

The [AIX version of mmap](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/m_bostechref/mmap.html) promises to zero-fill anonymous mappings:

> `MAP_ANONYMOUS`
>
> Specifies the creation of a new, anonymous memory region that is initialized to all zeros.

### HP-UX

According to nixdoc.net, the [HP-UX version of mmap](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man2/mmap.2.html) promises to zero-fill anonymous mappings:

> If `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is set in `flags`, a new memory region is created and initialized to all zeros.

### Solaris

The [Solaris version of mmap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37841/mmap-2.html) promises to zero-fill anonymous mappings:

> When `MAP_ANON` is set in `flags`, and `fildes` is set to -1, `mmap()` provides a direct path to return anonymous pages to the caller. This operation is equivalent to passing `mmap()` an open file descriptor on `/dev/zero` with `MAP_ANON` elided from the `flags` argument.

This Solaris man page gives us a way to get zero-filled memory pages without relying on the behavior of mmap used with the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag: do not use the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag, and create a mapping backed by the `/dev/zero` file. It would be useful to know the list of Unix-like operating systems providing the `/dev/zero` file, to see if this approach is more portable than using the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag (neither [/dev/zero](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html) nor [MAP_ANONYMOUS](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) are POSIX).

Interestingly, the [Wikipedia article about /dev/zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/zero) claims that `MAP_ANONYMOUS` was introduced to remove the need of opening `/dev/zero` when creating an anonymous mapping.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to say which ones promise what without simply exhaustively enumerating all man pages or other release documentation, but the underlying code that handles `MAP_ANON` is (usually? always?) also used to map in bss space for executables, and bss space needs to be zero-filled.  So it's pretty darn likely.

As for "giving you back your old values" (or some non-zero values but most likely, your old ones) if you unmap and re-map, it certainly seems possible, if some system were to be "lazy" about deallocation.  I have only used a few systems that support `mmap` in the first place (BSD and Linux derivatives) and neither one is lazy that way, at least, not in the kernel code handling `mmap`.

The reason `sbrk` might or might not zero-fill a "regrown" page is probably tied to history, or lack thereof.  The current FreeBSD code matches with what I recall from the old, pre-`mmap` days: there are two semi-secret variables, `minbrk` and `curbrk`, and both `brk` and `sbrk` will only invoke `SYS_break` (the real system call) if they are moving `curbrk` to a value that is at least `minbrk`.  (Actually, this looks slightly broken: `brk` has the at-least behavior but `sbrk` just adds its argument to `curbrk` and invokes `SYS_break`.  Seems harmless since the kernel checks, in `sys_obreak()` in `/sys/vm/vm_unix.c`, so a too-negative `sbrk()` will fail with `EINVAL`.)

I'd have to look at the Linux C library (and then perhaps kernel code too) but it may simply ignore attempts to "lower the break", and merely record a "logical break" value in libc.  If you have `mmap()` and no backwards compatibility requirements, you can implement `brk()` and `sbrk()` entirely in libc, using anonymous mappings, and it would be trivial to implement both of them as "grow-only", as it were.

Comment: I didn't know this until I looked it up but MAP_ANON isn't in POSIX.

Comment: @Olsonist: that's kind of surprising, but it adds to the "no hard-and-fast promises about MAP_ANON", to the extent that there's not even a promise that MAP_ANON will exist. :-)